Replace Hoover toilet fill valve diaphragm
The toilet has a Hoover 8121 Ballcock/Fill Valve, which the diaphragm seal was gone.
Rather than replace the entire assembly, elected to get the Master Plumber repair kit instead (if I could have I would have bought just a diaphragm) as it's the only one available locally.

I am confused on two points...

Not clear why the replacement kit comes with 2 diaphragm when the existing assembly clearly only had a single diaphragm. Do I seat both of them together or leave the second as a spare when the first next fails (aargh, circular problem!)?

I can't seem to figure out how to remove the seating nut from the existing. While the replacement has a centre hex shape for a key, the existing is circular. I can't see a seam, so it would also appear to be a single piece. In any case, no idea what tool would work.


I have replaced the plunger, single diaphragm and the screws. It seems to work fine.
MOEN make a similar replacement kit that does not include the seating nut or a second diaphragm, so maybe am OK and the extra parts in the "universal kit" are for a different model?
Existing Assembly

Replacement Nut


If it works, you’re fine.  Some kits include parts  for multiple problems or models.
